# I need to add several names in one Colum/Row in MySql through C# app

Tags: c#, mysql

// I don't have reputation to add Picture 
But my columns should be like: //

**idak | anavn | spejdere |**

I need to add several names in 'spejdere' row. I don't know if it is possible. Here is my code for adding one name in the 'spejdere'

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=*****";
                string Query = "update database.aktiviteter set spejdere='" + this.spe_txt.Text + "' where idak='" + this.idak_txt2.Text + "' ;";
                MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
                MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                try
                {
                    conDatabase.Open();
                    myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
                    MessageBox.Show("Spejder er tilknyttet");
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: At first you should consider using a parameterized sql query, in order to avoid sql injection (please look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). For parameterized queries in .NET look here http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Parameterized-Queries-ADO.Net.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't make a specific question or describe a problem, so I'll just guess that your database chokes on the string you pass.

There are many serious problems with your code:

1. Adding "multiple values" is a very bad design and breaks the most basic design rule in SQL. Just use a different table with a foreign key pointing to the parent table. Putting multiple values is a real nightmare should you need to query for a specific value, modify a specific value, or just do anything with the values you stored.
2. Creating a SQL statement by string concatenation is slow, error-prone and exposes you to SQL Injection attacks. Just putting the wrong character (e.g. another `'`) will translate the rest of the string as a SQL statement.
3. You forget to close the connection.

Jeff Attwood has a nice post about why raw queries are bad in [Give me parameterized SQL or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

You can easily convert your statement to a parameterized query like this:

```
string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=*****";
string Query = "update database.aktiviteter set spejdere=@param1 where idak=@param2 ;";
using(var connection= new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    var command= new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1",this.spe_txt.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2",this.idak_txt2.Text);

    connection.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

`using` ensures that the connection is closed and disposed when you no longer need it, even if an exception occurs

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis Kanavos! it was very helpful and the experience has been enormously rewarding

Answer (score 0):

While doing updates use ExecuteNonQuery method instead of ExecuteReader. Also don't forget to close the connection :)

```
try
{
    conDatabase.Open();
    int numberOfRowsUpdated = cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finnaly
{
    conDatabase.Close();
}
```